# Dynamically modify JSON file in bash script with jq - use heredocs or key assignments?

Tags: json, bash, jq

Below is the part of my JSON file, the JSON file itself is longer.

```
{
    "anomalyDetection": {
        "loadingTimeThresholds": {
            "enabled": false,
            "thresholds": []
        },
        "outageHandling": {
            "globalOutage": true,
            "localOutage": true,
            "localOutagePolicy": {
                "affectedLocations": 1,
                "consecutiveRuns": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I need to modify `affectedLocations` and `consecutiveRuns` values with supplied parameters, assign the modified JSON to a var which then is used during the API call.

I created two different solutions with bash to accomplish the above.

**Option 1 - use heredocs**

```
# Assign the template file to a template var
get_template() {
    read -r -d '' template <<JSONTEMPLATE
{
    "anomalyDetection": {
        "loadingTimeThresholds": {
            "enabled": false,
            "thresholds": []
        },
        "outageHandling": {
            "globalOutage": true,
            "localOutage": true,
            "localOutagePolicy": {
                "affectedLocations": 1,
                "consecutiveRuns": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
JSONTEMPLATE
}

modify_json_with_heredoc() {

    # Call the template var assignment
    get_template

    read -r -d '' json_keys_updated <<JSONSTRING
{
    "globalOutage": true,
    "localOutage": true,
    "localOutagePolicy": {
        "affectedLocations": ${1:-1},
        "consecutiveRuns": ${2:-2}
    }
}
JSONSTRING

    # Replace key values from the template with the updated parameters

    updated_JSON=$(jq --argjson update_outageHandling "$json_keys_updated" \
        '.anomalyDetection.outageHandling|=$update_outageHandling' \
        <<<"$template")
}
```

**Option 2 - modify keys in the JSON directly**

```
modify_json_with_vars() {

    # Call the template assignment
    get_template

    updated_JSON=$(jq --argjson update_affectedLocations "${1:-1}" --argjson update_consecutiveRuns "${2:-2}" \
        ' .anomalyDetection.outageHandling.globalOutage|=true
        | .anomalyDetection.outageHandling.localOutagePolicy.affectedLocations|=$update_affectedLocations
        | .anomalyDetection.outageHandling.localOutagePolicy.consecutiveRuns|=$update_consecutiveRuns' \
        <<<"$template")

}
```

I need to be able to call functions with/without parameters. If functions are called without parameters, then need to keep the default values for keys, that's why `${1:-1}` `${2:-2}` are there.

Both options work fine - for example,`modify_json_with_vars 2 3` or `modify_json_with_heredoc`. My question is which of the above is better/faster/safer, as well as more 'right' thing to do.

As I've mentioned, the template file is larger. At this moment I need to modify only the keys in the object `.anomalyDetection.outageHandling.localOutagePolicy`, however, in the future I might need to change other keys as well and need a solution which is scalable and maintainable.

I think that the first option is neater because jq is called only with one parameter. But if I will need to change keys all over the source template JSON file, probably the second option is more scalable.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What is the type of answer you are looking for? Seemingly you have suggestions worked out.

Comment: I'd say that given that jq has been build for json amendments, it would be the better solution. You can also test the efficiency of both options using the time command.

Comment: @Inian - while I have two working options, the question is - from the performance/usability/code safety perspective which one would be more preferable.

Comment: use `--arg` rather than `--arg-json` since your arguments are not JSON but plain shell strings.

Comment: @LéaGris when using --arg jq interprets parameter as a string. As a result, you will get "3" instead of 3 in the key assignment. With --argjson you won't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too would suggest a different approach for the reasons outlined below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function template {
    cat<<EOF
{
    "anomalyDetection": {
        "loadingTimeThresholds": {
            "enabled": false,
            "thresholds": []
        },
        "outageHandling": {
            "globalOutage": true,
            "localOutage": true,
            "localOutagePolicy": {
                "affectedLocations": 1,
                "consecutiveRuns": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
EOF
}

function modify_json() {
    template |  
    jq --argjson update_affectedLocations "${1:-1}" \
       --argjson update_consecutiveRuns "${2:-2}" '
       .anomalyDetection.outageHandling.localOutagePolicy
         |= (.affectedLocations |= $update_affectedLocations
             | .consecutiveRuns |= $update_consecutiveRuns )
    '
}

updated_JSON=$(modify_json 42 666)
echo "$updated_JSON"
```

### Considerations

1. It is generally ill-advised to write functions which set "global" variables (such as `$template`) if possible.  By defining a function (`template`), we also introduce only one name instead of one for the function and one for the variable.
2. It appears that the parameters `update_affectedLocations` and `update_consecutiveRuns` are supposed to be numbers, so using --argjson makes sense, especially if some resilience and simplicity are considerations.
3. The jq program achieves "DRY-ness" (i.e. it avoids unnecessary repetition) by using the update-assignment operator freely.
4. Using "|" at the beginning of lines in a jq program makes it easy to achieve a certain amount of visual elegance while highlighting the logic.

Notice also that the suggested script is quite succinct and uncomplicated, while being reasonably robust.

Some would deprecate using the keyword `function` to define shell functions, but it does make locating function definitions trivially easy, both for human eyes and human fingers at the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks. I took your suggestions and then slightly modified it - instead of  ``template |  
    jq '.....'`` I used process substitution ``jq '.....` < <(template)``.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is handling all the arguments within `jq`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Assign the template file to a template var
get_template() {
  template='{
    "anomalyDetection": {
        "loadingTimeThresholds": {
            "enabled": false,
            "thresholds": []
        },
        "outageHandling": {
            "globalOutage": true,
            "localOutage": true,
            "localOutagePolicy": {
                "affectedLocations": 1,
                "consecutiveRuns": 2
            }
        }
    }
}'
}

modify_json() {
  # Call the template assignment
  get_template

  updated_JSON=$(
    jq \
      --arg update_affectedLocations "$1" \
      --arg update_consecutiveRuns "$2" \
      --null-input \
      "$template"'|
if $update_affectedLocations | try tonumber catch false
then
  .anomalyDetection.outageHandling.localOutagePolicy.affectedLocations |= (
    $update_affectedLocations | tonumber
  )
else .
end |
if $update_consecutiveRuns | try tonumber catch false
then
  .anomalyDetection.outageHandling.localOutagePolicy.consecutiveRuns |= (
    $update_consecutiveRuns | tonumber
  )
else .
end '
  )
}

modify_json 42 666
echo "$updated_JSON"
```

Comment: What is the point to use --arg and then do additional logic if you can have --argjson getting the same result?

Comment: Also, how your code is handling default values for the ``affectedLocations`` and ``consecutiveRuns``? The fact that they are in the template fail does not mean that they are not needed - values in the template file might be gone/modified.