# dynamically changing values in multiple objects in json using jq

Tags: json, jq

The following file is taken from [Dynamically modify JSON file in bash script with jq - use heredocs or key assignments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64646374/dynamically-modify-json-file-in-bash-script-with-jq-use-heredocs-or-key-assign)

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function template {
    cat<<EOF
{
    "anomalyDetection": {
        "loadingTimeThresholds": {
            "enabled": false,
            "thresholds": []
        },
        "outageHandling": {
            "globalOutage": true,
            "localOutage": true,
            "localOutagePolicy": {
                "affectedLocations": 1,
                "consecutiveRuns": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
EOF
}

function modify_json() {
    template |  
    jq --argjson update_affectedLocations "${1:-1}" \
       --argjson update_consecutiveRuns "${2:-2}" '
       .anomalyDetection.outageHandling.localOutagePolicy
         |= (.affectedLocations |= $update_affectedLocations
             | .consecutiveRuns |= $update_consecutiveRuns )
    '
}

updated_JSON=$(modify_json 42 666)
echo "$updated_JSON"
```

In this , in addition to above changes in .anomalyDetection.outageHandling.localOutagePolicy Object , How to change the .enabled.key in " .anomalyDetection.loadingTimeThresholds" Object dynamically using the jq in the same modify_json function.

Actual output of the above script is below

```json
{
  "anomalyDetection": {
    "loadingTimeThresholds": {
      "enabled": false,
      "thresholds": []
    },
    "outageHandling": {
      "globalOutage": true,
      "localOutage": true,
      "localOutagePolicy": {
        "affectedLocations": 42,
        "consecutiveRuns": 666
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Am Expecting output like this, existing value anomalyDetection.loadingTimeThresholds.enabled also to be replaced by true in addition to above

```json
{
  "anomalyDetection": {
    "loadingTimeThresholds": {
      "enabled": true,
      "thresholds": []
    },
    "outageHandling": {
      "globalOutage": true,
      "localOutage": true,
      "localOutagePolicy": {
        "affectedLocations": 42,
        "consecutiveRuns": 666
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `bash` code that wraps `jq` isn't really relevant. Could you focus on showing what what you expect the result of `modify_json` to be?

Comment: @chepner , have amended the expected results in the Question section.

Answer (score 0):

You could (for example) simply prepend the following to the jq filter:

```
.anomalyDetection.loadingTimeThresholds.enabled = true |
```

Comment: Ok, But when give this as variable , its not invoking

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comment is too obscure for me.